# How to load the customers data to a table with border in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to load the data name, customerId, rentCost of customers into each cell of a table in a row. I am not sure which JavaScript code to use to accomplish that. I also need to style the table with css file with border = 1.
*I need to be able to add more data to the table using a html form later.
Thanks for your help in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script>
script>
var customers= [
{
name: "Kim Knudson", 
customerID:"541", 
rentCost:"$221", 

},
{       
name: "Henry Lewis", 
customerID:"321", 
rentCost:"$555",
}
];

</script>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Customer ID</td>
    <td>Rent</td>

</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. Put your `<script>` either in `<head>` or `<body>` section. 2. What have you tried so far?

Comment: You have already asked this question over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824191/how-to-dynamically-load-the-data-from-customers-to-a-table-in-javascript-within. Why asking it again??

Answer (score 0):

Use `for` loop to go through all records in `customers`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
    console.log(customers[i]['name']);
}
```

With this it's up to you, how you will display them in table (see [insertRow()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp) method, it should be what you want).

Answer (score 0):

check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3A3L/) for working example. change your html like this:

```
<div id = "myDiv">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Customer ID</td>
    <td>Rent</td>

</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

change your javascript like this and put it to run on load. also this will add border t your table.

```
window.onload=function() {
    var customers= [
    {
    name: "Kim Knudson", 
    customerID:"541", 
    rentCost:"$221", 

    },
    {       
    name: "Henry Lewis", 
    customerID:"321", 
    rentCost:"$555",
    }
    ];

    var tableData = "<table style='border: 1px solid black;'><tr><td>Name</td><td>Customer ID</td><td>Rent</td></tr>";
    for(i=0;i<customers.length;i++)
    {
        tableData += "<tr><td>" + customers[i].name + "</td><td>" + customers[i].customerID + "</td><td>" + customers[i].rentCost + "</td></tr>"
    }
    document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = tableData + "</table>";
};
```

and your html table is recreated with the data in your json object.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JavaScript `insertRow` and `insertCell` DOM functions for tables:

```
var customers = [{
    name: "Kim Knudson",
    customerID: "541",
    rentCost: "$221"
}, {
    name: "Henry Lewis",
    customerID: "321",
    rentCost: "$555"
}];
var tbl = document.querySelector("body>table");
for (var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
    var customer = customers[i];
    var row = tbl.insertRow(i + 1);
    var nameCell = row.insertCell(0);
    nameCell.innerText = customer.name;
    var idCell = row.insertCell(1);
    idCell.innerText = customer.customerID;
    var rentCell = row.insertCell(2);
    rentCell.innerText = customer.rentCost;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I recommend to use jQuery for this, you can use the following code as a guideline:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <style>

        #table tr td {
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }

    </style>

    <script>
        var customers= [
        {
        name: "Kim Knudson", 
        customerID:"541", 
        rentCost:"$221", 

        },
        {       
        name: "Henry Lewis", 
        customerID:"321", 
        rentCost:"$555",
        }
        ];

        // this function will executed after the dom is loaded
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            // loop over each element in the customers array
            $.each( customers, function(key, value ) {
                // append the new row to the table
                $('#table tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + value.name + '</td><td>' + value.customerID + '</td><td>' + value.rentCost + '</td></tr>');
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
<table id="table">
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Customer ID</td>
    <td>Rent</td>

</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Some things I also recommend:

- I added the CSS style on the head for simplicity but you should move it to a css file (same thing with the javascript code)
- Inside the "each" loop I adding the "

Hope that helps.